# UIBarButtonItem with UIButton as custom view doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to display a custom `UIButton` as a `UINavigationItem`'s `rightBarButtonItem`.
I wrote the following code:

```
UIButton *inviteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[inviteButton setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
inviteButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
inviteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
inviteButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
inviteButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

UIBarButtonItem *inviteButtonContainer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:inviteButton];

viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = inviteButtonContainer;
```

Nothing shows up in my navigation bar.

However, with the following code, I can see a basic button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *inviteButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invite"
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                                target:self
                                                                action:nil];

viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = inviteButton;
```

But it's obviously not what I am after, since I am looking to play with the button appearance.

**Edit**
I was trying to add the same instance of `UIBarButtonItem` (`inviteButtonContainer`) to many navigation bars. Doing that, it's visible on the last navigation bar only.
However, if I use the same instance of a simple `UIBarButtonItem` (without custom view), it's displayed on every navigation bars. Any idea why?

Comment: I just did as per your suggestion, but doesn't change anything. `UIButton` is already a subclass of `UIView` anyway, so I don't see your point.

Comment: where did u put that code ?

Comment: what is viewController ?

Comment: your code works perfectly on my end, the "Invite" title isn't displayed correctly (because of it's length), but the button is there. I run it on the simulator and on an iPhone 5. You're probably not using in the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, just change this line:

```
    viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = inviteButtonContainer;
```

to

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = inviteButtonContainer;
```

**From the Documentation:**

> The navigation item used to represent the view controller in a
>   parent's navigation bar.

`self` itself represents that it belongs to view controller , so there is no need to mention the view controller instance to add the navigation item.

Answer (score 1):

-> To display custom button in a view controller in which custom bar button is crated (i.e. in self) :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *inviteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [inviteButton setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    inviteButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30);
    inviteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    inviteButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    inviteButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    UIBarButtonItem *inviteButtonContainer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:inviteButton];

    controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = inviteButtonContainer;
}
```

-> To display custom bar button in a view controller that is about to present

eg. To display a view controller after a cell is selected in table view

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DjDetailsViewController *controller = (DjDetailsViewController *) 
    [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DjDetailsViewController"];

    UIButton *inviteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [inviteButton setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    inviteButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30);
    inviteButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    inviteButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    inviteButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    UIBarButtonItem *inviteButtonContainer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:inviteButton];

    controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = inviteButtonContainer;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

I didn’t done major. I just used your code and change frame of custom bar button.
I hope this will help you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You issue is with your invite button initialiser:

```
UIButton *inviteButton = [UIButton UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

`UIButtonTypeCustom` is an enum value not a class method/convenience constructor.

use

```
UIButton *inviteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo while writing the question. I couldn't have complied with such a code anyway. I edited my question.

Comment: It could be that your frame is wrong on the inviteButton (too small for the text). try calling 
`[inviteButton sizeToFit];` after setting the text.  Also see if it work when using `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect`